# UITableView scrolling too small

Tags: uitableview, scroll

I have an IPad App which has a little UITableView in another View, but when I add enough cells, the ScrollView does not grow, why?

@edit: I mean I am not able to scroll because it bounces back to the top.

Here's the code for the framechange of the tableview:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
[super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
    ||  toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    CGRect rect = _table.frame; 
    rect.size.height = 565;
    _table.frame = rect;
    //_table.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_table.contentSize.width, 1000); // Doesn't work
}else{
    CGRect rect = _table.frame;
    rect.size.height = 820;
    _table.frame = rect;
    _table.contentSize = rect.size;
    //_table.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_table.contentSize.width, 1000); // Doesn't work
}}
```

Comment: Could you include some code? It'd be easier to help if we see what you're trying to do.

Comment: TableView is a Subclass of scrollView I tried to change the content size but no effect. I am not able to scroll to the last cell.